# Can I skip これは and この in questions?

Tags: grammar

I know これは誰の本ですか。/この本は誰のですか means "whose book is that". I also know that if you want to say "this is my book" you can just say　私の本です。or even 私のです。However, does skipping これ/この apply to the question as well? Can I just ask 誰の本ですか or is it incorrect grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the book you are referring to is obvious, yes 誰の本ですか is quite acceptable.